# JSONDecodeError error when trying to pull playlists from spotify using spotipy

Tags: python, python-3.x, spotify, spotipy

I'm using the default instructions provided by docs in spotipy, I setup my app in the spotify dev dashboard, and checked my credentials, but am still getting this error code:

`JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth

YOUR_APP_CLIENT_ID = "myappclientid"
YOUR_APP_CLIENT_SECRET = "myclientsecret"
YOUR_APP_REDIRECT_URI = "mycallback"
SCOPE = "playlist-read-private"

sp = spotipy.Spotify(
    auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(
        client_id=YOUR_APP_CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret=YOUR_APP_CLIENT_SECRET,
        redirect_uri=YOUR_APP_REDIRECT_URI,
        scope=SCOPE,
    )
)

sp.current_user_playlists(limit = 50)
```

full traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\my_spotify_playlists\example.py in 
     14 )
     15 
---> 16 sp.current_user_playlists(limit = 50)

c:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py in current_user_playlists(self, limit, offset)
    635                 - offset - the index of the first item to return
    636         """
--> 637         return self._get("me/playlists", limit=limit, offset=offset)
    638 
    639     def playlist(self, playlist_id, fields=None, market=None, additional_types=("track",)):

c:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py in _get(self, url, args, payload, **kwargs)
    321             kwargs.update(args)
    322 
--> 323         return self._internal_call("GET", url, payload, kwargs)
    324 
    325     def _post(self, url, args=None, payload=None, **kwargs):

c:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py in _internal_call(self, method, url, payload, params)
    245         if not url.startswith("http"):
    246             url = self.prefix + url
--> 247         headers = self._auth_headers()
    248 
    249         if "content_type" in args["params"]:
...
    354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Search that exact error text and you'll see that it means json tried to decode an empty file or string. If you post the full traceback message we can get an idea of whether it was in the spotipy package. It may mean an error code wasn't checked correctly. It could be that one of your parameters is wrong or spotipy has a bug.

Comment: @tdelaney posted trackback

Comment: The error message says the `sp.current_user_playlists(...)` call is on line 35, which does not match the posted code...

Comment: I commented some stuff out and didn't include, but i'll repost

Comment: Okay, the error is in spotipy and it would take a look at the source to debug further. Searching the web with "+spotify JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)" yielded discssions on things like "invalid redirect" that magically went away. But basically, a spotipy response had an error and instead of giving you more info, they just raise a JSON error. Could be a good discussion on a spotify dev board.

Comment: The line number issue is trivial, its clear that the spotify call is the problem.

Comment: Somebody on Windows resolved the problem by running admin which hints at a firewall issue.

Comment: can you link me the post where the user ran it as admin?

Comment: No error your code in my Windows 11. I using Python 3.11.4 and Spotipy 2.23.0

Comment: I deleted my .cache file and it's working again